# Why does Python Requests throw this error when attempting to use it with Tumblr?

Tags: python, oauth, tumblr, python-requests

This is my Oauth code:

```
auth = OAuth1(client_key=consumer_key,
              client_secret=consumer_secret,
              resource_owner_key=access_key,
              resource_owner_secret=access_secret,
              signature_type='auth_header')

r = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
print r
```

Error:

```
   r = requests.get(url,auth = auth)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 38, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 259, in request
    prep = req.prepare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 197, in prepare
    p.prepare_auth(self.auth)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 329, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/core.py", line 41, in __call__
    decoded_body = extract_params(r.data)
AttributeError: 'PreparedRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Please show more error messages.

Comment: Have added the entire error message.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're using Requests 1.0.0 or later. It was a backwards-incompatible release and this error happens because [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) is not yet compatible with it. Some work has been done to fix this, but there hasn't been yet a new release. See [issue #1](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/issues/1) of requests-oauthlib.

Right now your options are:

1. Downgrade to requests 0.14.2, which should work with request_oauthlib 0.2.0.
2. Upgrade to [the git version](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) of request_oauthlib, which might work well enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to try a library that wraps Requests, there's [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth). I can even give you a working Tumblr example:

```
from rauth import OAuth1Service

import re
import webbrowser

# Get a real consumer key & secret from http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps
tumblr = OAuth1Service(
    consumer_key='gKRR414Bc2teq0ukznfGVUmb41EN3o0Nu6jctJ3dYx16jiiCsb',
    consumer_secret='DcKJMlhbCHM8iBDmHudA9uzyJWIFaSTbDFd7rOoDXjSIKgMYcE',
    name='tumblr',
    request_token_url='http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token',
    access_token_url='http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize',
    base_url='https://api.tumblr.com/v2/')

request_token, request_token_secret = tumblr.get_request_token()

authorize_url = tumblr.get_authorize_url(request_token)

print 'Visit this URL in your browser: ' + authorize_url
webbrowser.open(authorize_url)
authed_url = raw_input('Copy URL from your browser\'s address bar: ')
verifier = re.search('\oauth_verifier=([^#]*)', authed_url).group(1)

session = tumblr.get_auth_session(request_token,
                                  request_token_secret,
                                  method='POST',
                                  data={'oauth_verifier': verifier})

user = session.get('user/info').json()['response']['user']

print 'Currently logged in as: {name}'.format(name=user['name'])
```

Rauth 0.5.3 will work with Requests 1.1.0 (and likely 1.0.0). If you give it a try, let me know if you have any further questions!

Full disclosure, I maintain rauth.

Comment: rauth just saved me- nice work Max, keep it up- there's no other Python OAuth lib I can count on